# Find two numbers in array x,y where x<y, x repeats at least n/3 times and y at least n/4 times

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have been struggling to solve an array problem with linear time,
The problem is:
Assuming we are given an array A [1...n] write an algorithm that return true if:
There are two numbers in the array x,y that have the following:

1. x < y
2. x repeats more than n/3 times
3. y repeats more than n/4 times

I have tried to write the following java program to do so assuming we have a sorted array but I don't think it is the best implementation.

```
    public static boolean solutionManma(){
    int [] arr = {2,2,2,3,3,3};
    int n = arr.length;
    int xCount = 1;
    int yCount = 1;
    int maxXcount= xCount,maxYCount = yCount;
    int currX = arr[0];
    int currY = arr[n-1];

    for(int i = 1; i < n-2;i++){
        int right = arr[n-2-i+1];
        int left = arr[i];

        if(currX == left){
            xCount++;
        }
        else{
            maxXcount = Math.max(xCount,maxXcount);
            xCount = 1;
            currX = left;
        }
        if(currY == right){
            yCount++;
        }
        else {
            maxYCount = Math.max(yCount,maxYCount);
            yCount = 1;
            currY = right;
        }

    }
    return (maxXcount > n/3 && maxYCount > n/4);
}
```

If anyone has an algorithm idea for this kind of issue (preferably O(n)) I would much appreciate it because I got stuck with this one.

Comment: 1. Step through the array to build a hash `h` whose keys are unique values in `A` and whose values are frequencies of the numbers in `A`. Step 2. Create arrays `a3` and `a4` containing, respectively: a) keys from `h` having values greater than `n/3`; b) keys from `h` having values greater than `n/4` and less than or equal to `n/3`. Step 3. Compute `x` equal to the minimum value in `a3` and `y` as the maximum value of the maximum values of `a3`  or `a4`. All three steps are O(n) provided key lookups in Step 1 are regarded as O(1).

Comment: Further to my previous comment, observations in @rici's answer tell us that `a3` will contain 1 or 2 values and `a4` will contain 0, 1 or 2 values. rici does employ a superior algorithm, however.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of this problem is to find in linear time and constant space the values which occur more than n/4 times. (Note: the text of your question says "more than" and the title says "at least". Those are not the same condition. This answer is based on the text of your question.)

There are at most three values which occur more than n/4 times, and a list of  such values must also include any value which occurs more than n/3 times.

The algorithm we'll use returns a list of up to three values. It only guarantees that all values which satisfy the condition are in the list it returns. The list might include other values, and it does not provide any information about the precise frequencies.

So a second pass is necessary, which scans the vector a second time counting the occurrences of each of the three values returned. Once you have the three counts, it's simple to check whether the smallest value which occurs more than n/3 times (if any) is less than the largest value which occurs more than n/4 times.

To construct the list of candidates, we use a generalisation of the Boyer-Moore majority vote algorithm, which finds a value which occurs more than n/2 times. The generalisation, [published in 1982 by J. Misra and D. Gries](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/misra/scannedPdf.dir/FindRepeatedElements.pdf), uses `k-1` counters, each possibly associated with a value, to identify values which might occur more than `1/k` times. In this case, `k` is 4 and so we need three counters.

Initially, all of the counters are 0 and are not associated with any value. Then for each value in the array, we do the following:

- If there is a counter associated with that value, we increment it.
- If no counter is associated with that value but some counter is at 0, we associate that counter with the value and increment its count to 1.
- Otherwise, we decrement every counter's count.

Once all the values have been processed, the values associated with counters with positive counts are the candidate values.

For a general implementation where `k` is not known in advance, it would be possible to use a hash-table or other key-value map to identify values with counts. But in this case, since it is known that `k` is a small constant, we can just use a simple vector of three value-count pairs, making this algorithm O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: I would complement your answer had it not be proven in a comment that the question cannot be answered. :-)

Comment: @cary: an assertion is not a proof. :-)

Comment: It was a small mistake but I cannot let it go: I meant "compliment".

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the following solution, using the following assumption:

In an array of length `n` there will be at most `n` different numbers

The key feature will be to count the frequency of occurance for each different input using a histogram with `n` bins, meaning `O(n)` space. The algorithm will be as follows:

1. create a histogram vector with `n` bins, initialized to zeros
2. for index `ii` in the length of the input array `a`

   2.1. Increase the value: `hist[a[ii]] +=1`
3. set `found_x` and `found_y` to `False`
4. for the `ii`th bin in the histogram, check:

   4.1. if `found_x == False`

   4.1.1. if `hist[ii] > n/3`, set found_`x = True` and set `x = ii`

   4.2. else if `found_y == False`

   4.2.1. if `hist[ii] > n/4`, set `y = ii` and return `x, y`

### Explanation

In the first run over the array you document the occurance frequency of all the numbers. In the run over the histogram array, which also has a length of `n`, you check the occurrence. First you check if there is a number that occurred more than `n/3` times and if there is, for the rest of the numbers (by default larger than `x` due to the documentation in the histogram) you check if there is another number which occurred more than `n/4` times. if there is, you return the found `x` and `y` and if there isn't you simply return not found after covering all the bins in the histogram.

As far as time complexity, you goover the input array once and you go over the histogram with the same length once, therefore the time complexity is `O(n)` is requested.